# Matlab: compute the sum of elements in the lower portion of a matrix

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, diagonal

[image][image]I have to develop a Matlab function that computes the sum of the elements in the reverse diagonal, and the elements to the right of the reverse diagonal.  **Sum (A) = 38 ;  Sum (B) = 40;   Sum (C) = 25;**

enter image description here[image]

Can somebody provide me a solution on how to go about using looping to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can do the homework yourself, but try flipping the matrix and then take the upper triangular component

Comment: Thanks; used flip and diag functions to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

For a n×m Matrix:

1. Set the `sum` to 0, `column` to 1 and `top` to n (assuming `(n,1)` is the bottom-left corner of the matrix)
2. Add to the `sum` all elements in current column which row number is **more or equal** to the `top`.
3. Add 1 to `column`. If `column` is greater than `m` we are done.
4. Subtract 1 from `top`. If `top` is `0`, set `top` to `1`.
5. Go to 1.

Answer (score 1):

For matrix `M`

```
Mysum = sum(sum(tril(rot90(M,-1))))
```